# How to fix error with importing skforecast using Jupyter

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

When I use `pip install skforecast` in Jupyter, the install completes successfully.

Next, when I use `from skforecast.ForecasterAutoreg import ForecasterAutoreg` I get the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skforecast'

I have tried pip and pip3 for all 3 suggested installs in the docs: https://joaquinamatrodrigo.github.io/skforecast/0.4.3/index.html

Any advice on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the module installed? Check if pip list command

Comment: yes, I confirmed that version 0.4.2 is installed.

Comment: Are you utilizing envs or anything like that?

Comment: No, I am not. Just opened a new notebook and installed skforecast. This works fine for another other packages, so I am not sure why it's not in this case.

Comment: on Windows we could make a small check by opening command prompt and typing `python -c "import skforecast"`. This calls your "default" Python and if you still see that error then perhaps need to re-install `skforecast`

Comment: You restarted the kernel after running `%pip install skforecast` in your notebook?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when trying to run a script in JupyterLab from a virtual environment. What worked for me was to specify which kernel to use. To do that:

1. Navigate to your virtual environment directory and activate it. In my case on windows 11, in a terminal: `{virtual_environment_path}\Scripts\activate.bat`
2. `pip install ipykernel` if you don't have it already installed
3. In the same terminal, navigate to your project folder (typically the parent directory of your virtual environment) and `python -m ipykernel install --user --name={your virtual environment name}`
4. Open your project with JupyterLab/Jupyter, go to the kernel menu and click "change kernel".
   [Change Kernel Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYt2e.png)
5. There you can select the kernel with you virtual environment name in it. Now your kernel can access all and only the packages installed in your virtual environment.
   [Select the virtual envitornment kernel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OD17M.png)

Anyway, credit to this guide, which I almost copypasted:
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-use-virtual-environment-inside-jupyter-lab-sina-khoshgoftar

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32673108)

Comment: Alright, will work on it to have it today :P